# 'join' is unavailable: call the 'joinWithSeparator()' method on the sequence of elements

Tags: swift, swift2

I am developing an app in which i wanted to add a mobile number/ Phone number. For which I added the code provided but in swift 2 it is giving an error to  let decimalString = "".join(components) as NSString this code as 'join' is unavailable: call the 'joinWithSeparator()' method on the sequence of elements. So I tried to replace the code with return jointWithSeparator() but this ain't helping.

Answer (score 0):

> 'join' is unavailable: call the 'joinWithSeparator()' method on the sequence of elements.

- **The sequence of elements** is the array (`components`).
- **Call on** specifies the portion of the expression left of the dot.

---

In Swift 1 `join` is called on the separator

```
"".join(components)
```

In Swift 2 `joinWithSeparator` is called on the sequence of elements

```
components.joinWithSeparator("")
```